# Xamarin.Forms opening url from https://docs.google.com/viewer?url={pdf} in webview

Tags: pdf, xamarin.forms, webview

After updating xamarin.forms to version 5.0.0.2196. Links from the document loaded into the webview through the link [https://docs.google.com/viewer?url={pdf}](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=%7Bpdf%7D) do not work. The WebView.Navigating event does not fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some normal suggestions for you

1. Update `Xamarin.Forms` to the latest(5.0.0.2244) to see if problem persists .
2. Change the url to the `https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url={0}` .

Refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/383713/xamarin-forms-issue-with-showing-a-pdf-files-using.html.